# Prometheus recording rules convert name to label

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to create a recording rule to combine some data with a regular expression. But i want to keep the original name by converting it into a label, such as

```
errors{old_name="__name__"} = {__name__=~"counter_status_5\\d{2}.+"}
```

But the label ist set to the literal `__name__` and not to the original name of the counter.

Is there a way to get the intended result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with with label_replace, but the real issue here is that you're not using labels and this additional `old_name` label will only make expressions more complicated and error prone.

Presuming you can't fix this at the other end, https://www.robustperception.io/extracting-labels-from-legacy-metric-names/ is a workaround for this on the Prometheus ingestion side.

Comment: Your answer was better than the question and pointed me to a much better solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Rename the label:**

```
label_replace(sort_desc(count by(__name__, job) ({__name__=~".+"})),"label_name","$1","__name__", "(.+)")
```